# Calling a method in one code behind from another code behind in WPF

Tags: wpf, methods, code-behind

What is the best way of calling a method that is in the code behind of a window from the code behind of another window? For example I have a method `ShowSamples()` in the code behind of my `MainWindow`, I have a separate window `Window2`, once the user clicks a Button on `Window2` I want the `ShowSamples()` method in the code behind of `MainWindow` to be executed. How would I go about achieving this?

NOTE: The windows do not have a reference to each other, they do not inherit from a given class and do not have a parent-child relation ship, 2 completely separate windows in 1 application.

Comment: Do the codebehinds have a reference to each other? Are they in a parent-child relationship?

Comment: No they're not, sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: You can get a reference to you applications current main window with `Application.Current.MainWindow`

Comment: You really should not be doing this i think...

Comment: @ H.B. why is that? and what do you recommend? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to call a method on your current MainWindow, you can access the applications main window, and call its method using a cast. Assuming your MainWindow is called SamplesWindow, this should work:

```
((SamplesWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ShowSamples();
```